# Is there a term that means doing "funny hand gestures”?

Tags: single-word-requests, gestures

For example, the I Love You gesture:

[image]

Or the Vulcan salute:

[image]

Or the V for Victory:

[image]

- What is the general name for all of these actions?
- Would you say they are funny hand gestures?
- What verb should it be: *raising* or *showing*?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118866/discussion-on-question-by-ooker-is-there-a-term-that-means-doing-funny-hand-ges).

Answer (score 2):

In some contexts, notably in hiphop culture and in the dance/rave scene, people talk of [throwing shapes](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Throwing%20shapes)